# Generate odometry from encoders, cmd_vel, differential velocity

Tags: slam, navigation, encoders, robot-localization, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm trying to mix **/imu/data** with my robot (Clearpath Husky) odometry by using the [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package in order to use them with the [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) package with my RealSense and SICK data.
I'm doing this because I want to improve my 3D map by adding IMU information in RTAB-Map.

I already have the /imu/data information, but I don't have the [/odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) topic.
During my field tests, I only recorded encoders, differential_velocity and cmd_vel.

Is it possbible to use these topics to generate the /odometry message needed by the robot_localization package?

I hope you can help me!
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239912/generate-odometry-from-encoders,-cmd_vel,-differential-velocity/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The EKF in `r_l` supports multiple input message types. See [this](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization#Features) section of the wiki. You aren't required to have any set of input topics; you can have as many or as few as you want (though more is usually better).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1